# How to test whether any exception was rescued?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, exception, testing, testcase

Is there a way to find out whether any exception was raised and rescued during the execution of some code?

Preferably in tests written with `ActiveSupport::TestCase` and not RSpec

Is there any global ruby exception stack or something, which I could check?

Comment: Setup your fixture so it would raise the error and verify that the error didn't leak.

Comment: @ndn how do I raise an error from within a fixture? Btw, the error is not in the data, but in the code itself..

Comment: By fixture I didn't mean rail's fixtures, I meant the preconditions/environment in which you run your tests. Just make sure that whatever is needed for the error to be raised is done in the setup.

Comment: @ndn ah, I see. It's only that I'm running into this issue while in another test case where I don't want exceptions, but they apparently occurred anyway, was silently rescued, and caused my test case to fail due to some code not being executed below the point where the exception was raised. Thus I would have liked if there were any global ruby exception stack or something which I in the test could just check was empty.

Comment: *"another test case where I don't want exceptions, but they apparently occurred anyway"* - what caused the failure? You either did the error flow setup for tests that shouldn't be concerned with it or you have an issue with the implementation itself.

Comment: It was a stub (I wrote in the same test case) of a third party service, which didn't return proper JSON (it returned `""` instead of `"{}"`), so the `JSON.parse(response.body)` part of the implementation raised an `JSON::ParserError "A JSON text must at least contain two octets!"`. The third party service in production always returns proper JSON though, so I only ran into this problem in my test case.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what the issue is. Obviously in this case you should stub similarly to what you get from production. Is the problem that you had hard time finding why the test is failing due to the exception getting silenced? If yes - why does your code catch and silence `JSON::ParserError`? Is that the legitimate failure you want to guard against or did you just not specify the type of exceptions and `JSON::ParserError` got rescued incidentally?

Comment: @ndn _"Is the problem that you had hard time finding why the test is failing due to the exception getting silenced?"_ Yes. I didn't realize that JSON.parse would fail on "", so I just used the stub that WebMock suggested me, which returned "" (which I will fix https://github.com/bblimke/webmock/issues/688). The code in our app catches all StandardErrors (not my doing), because it is code that logs events, and ideally shouldn't negatively effect the user in production, just log any error to an error log and move on.

Comment: I see. So is it safe to say that you are not looking for a way to test for rescues, rather than debug potential rescues?

Comment: I'm asking because there is a way to do that, but you definitely shouldn't be putting it anywhere in your code.

Comment: @ndn Yes, that would be safe to say. :-) Care to share the way to do that in an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As clarified in the comments, OP needed it for debug purposes as opposed to write tests with it.

---

[`Kernel#set_trace_func`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Kernel.html#method-i-set_trace_func) lets you intercept low level events such as an error being raised:

```
set_trace_func(proc do |event, *_|
  puts 'Raised!' if event == 'raise'
end)

raise 'Oh, no!' rescue :foo
```

You can run `#set_trace_func` before the code you were trying to debug. If no exception was raised, but a raise was registered by the hook - someone rescued it.

---

This can create some noise depending on what you are executing. Fortunately, you can filter it down by file and line:

```
set_trace_func(proc do |event, file, line, *_|
  if event == 'raise' && file == 'test.rb' && line == 42
    puts "Raised on #{file}:#{line}!"
  end
end)
```

---

It even gives you the binding, so you can drop down a debugger:

```
require 'irb'

set_trace_func(proc do |event, *_, error_binding, _|
  error_binding.irb if event == 'raise'
end)

def foo
  bar = 42
  raise 'Oh, no!' rescue :baz
end

foo

# Opens an irb
# > bar # => 42
```

Comment: Thanks! This was beyond great!

Answer (score 7):

If you want to be a monster, you can instrument the errors themselves:

```
class StandardError
  @@called = false

  def initialize
    @@called = true
    super
  end

  def self.called
    @@called
  end
end

#test it out like so:

def raise_arg_error
  raise ArgumentError
rescue
end

puts ArgumentError.called #false
raise_arg_error
puts ArgumentError.called #true
```

Great for ad hoc sanity checks. Terrible for production code.

Comment: Interesting approach! Maybe I could do this only in the test code.. (not sure if that would be wise according to testing-methodology best practises though..). Why is it terrible for production code exactly? The extra attribute doesn't alter the way StandardError naturally works, so it wouldn't necessarily break other programmer's expectations..

Comment: @Magne It's a nice little wtf for a new developer to come onto your project and discover. And then he's going to make use of it to implement an actual production feature.

Comment: `StandardError.new` also sets `@@called` to `true`, even though no exception was raised.

Comment: @fylooi well, it won't be a wtf to discover it if it doesn't break expected way StandardError naturally works..? If another programmer uses it to implement an actual production feature it could get really bad, I agree. Sure, monkey-patching might create a potentially dangerous precedence. But it's hard to guard against other programmer's folly.. except maybe documenting the monkey patching and advicing against building on top of it in production code (or further monkey-patching)..

Comment: Bug happens. Developer can't figure out the root cause of it. Boss breathing down developer's neck and rumbling about deadlines. Developer decides to put in a production workaround to to monitor and fix the side effects of the bug instead. Hey, somebody did that before, I'll just copy the code! (I've seen somebody do this before btw)